# angular2+ form Validator.pattern

Tags: regex, angular

I hope the form input value **not contains any** backspace or linefeed char, so I use the Validators.pattern to do, but failed, how this reg should be?

```
Validators.pattern(/(?![\b|\n])/)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?![\b|\n])` pattern presents a negative lookahead that matches a *location* that is not followed with a backspace, `|` or  a newline. It does not guarantee that the whole string does not match this pattern.

You are looking for

```
Validators.pattern(/^[^\b\n]+$/)
```

Or

```
Validators.pattern("[^\b\n]+")
```

Note that string patterns are wrapped in `^...$` (="anchored") automatically.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^` - start of a negated character class

  - `\b` - a backspace (inside a character class, it is always parsed as a backspace)
  - `\n` - an LF symbol
- `]+` - end of the character class, repeat 1+ times
- `$` -  end of string.

Answer (score 0):

What about **every character but spaces and line feeds** ?

```
Validators.pattern(^[^\s\n]*$)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the argument in quotes :
Validators.pattern('/(?![\b|\n])/')

Comment: Signature of the method : `static pattern(pattern: string | RegExp): ValidatorFn`

Comment: And if you want to put it in quotes, you need to remove the slashes, as they are defining a regex.